# hashlips dont run node.js

Tags: node.js, visual-studio

hi i'm trying to run hashlips for making nft collections
but at the start for running node.js
it shows me this error

npm WARN old lockfile
npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm,
npm WARN old lockfile so supplemental metadata must be fetched from the registry.
npm WARN old lockfile
npm WARN old lockfile This is a one-time fix-up, please be patient...
npm WARN old lockfile

added 65 packages, and audited 66 packages in 27s

6 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

6 vulnerabilities (3 moderate, 3 high)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.